# Server Manufacturer Offering 4 year warranty?

Tags: warranty

I'm looking for a server to build a high availability cluster solution. The requirements ask for 4 year warranty.

I have been looking at IBM, HP, DELL, Fujitsu and seems 3 year warranty is standar.

Is there any manufacturer offering longer warranties?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whichever manufacturer you choose will be hounding you to renew your warranty 3 years from now. For info, [this type of question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is considered [off topic](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions) here, and will likely get closed.

Comment: @Bryan Actually, in this case I disagree. This is scoped beyond "find me a..." and the answers are generalizable across a broad scope.

Comment: Are they aware of how cost ineffective longer warranties are?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Not convinced, but I'll perhaps bring it up on meta when I've got more time.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: Also consider joining the ServerFault [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) where discussion covers a wide range of topics, and shopping question rules are relaxed

Comment: All of them offer up to 5-year extended support. For instance, the [HP Care Pack](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/2542161). THey can also be extended per-year after the initial warranty expires.

Comment: I know for a fact that Dell will warranty all their servers and server equipment for *at least* 5 years, and up to 7 in some cases. The cost of extending the warranty all the way out to that point will make your eyes water, but they'll do it. And if they do it then I'd say that their competitors at the same tier will do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all of them - basic warranty on almost every server I've seen it 3 years, but you can pay a bit extra to extend it a few more years.

Picking a random Dell server, A PowerEdge 720, upgrading the default 3 year 5x10 hardware only next business day warranty to 5 years is $919.  You get that option when configuring it.

Not only do they offer it - if you call a sales rep they will practically beg you to extend the warranty - it's a huge profit for them.

Comment: The key thing here is that most of the time these extended warranties are not called *warranties* they're called *support/service contracts*. But they do the same thing as the warranty.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all major manufacturers will extend their default warranty to 5 or 7 years at the time of purchase. You should take a minute to call some sales reps and gather this information for yourself.